# Calling function N times in public MainWindow()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xZLc69ZnLkWWRuaE9ycmhIXzg/view?usp=sharing]
This is the entire project - vs2013.

[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1xZLc69ZnLkWWRuaE9ycmhIXzg/view?usp=sharing)You can see how the `FindVisualChildren()` works to assign every letter to a button's content, I need to do this for every word on the file, but it only works one time.

[image]

I have a text file, with 10 words (one per line). Once the word is read, it's placed into a text box, and spread, letter by letter, in order to be assigned to a button content in joint with some random letters to fill all the buttons. This step is made by using the `FindVisualChildren()` method.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
//Add random letters to all buttons
foreach (Button tb in FindVisualChildren<Button>(panel))
{
    tb.Content = resultsChar[array[iconta]];  
    tb.Click += Button_Click;
    ++iconta;
}
```

Once all the letters are assigned, the user must create the word using every letter in every button, when the word is organized as corresponds to the one in the text box, then another word is called from the text, and the letters must be reassigned to the buttons with other random letters.

Everything works great, but just the first time. After that, I can't call the `FindVisualChildren()` method n times. This thing just work for the first word, and if I  put this inside a `while` loop, just shows me the last word. not step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, it's impossible to know what exactly that problem is. From your problem description, it sounds like you might be running some code in the constructor, which should instead be placed elsewhere so that it can safely run multiple times.

That said, I do agree with the basic motivation (though not the presentation at all) of the comment that explains that you should not be messing directly with the visual tree at all.

In many APIs, and WPF especially, the "right way" to do things is to create a custom class — your "view model — which is a type that maintains the state of your program *in a completely separate and independent way from the visual aspect of your program*. In your code example, this class would keep track of the word and letters to be displayed, and any other state for the program's underlying logic, as well as any methods for controlling or modifying that state.

As an example, I wrote a class that *could* serve as the view model in your program:

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private const int _kcolumnCount = 6;
    private const int _krowCount = 4;

    private string _word;

    public ObservableCollection<char> Letters { get; private set; }

    public string Word
    {
        get { return _word; }
        set { _UpdateValue(ref _word, value); }
    }

    public int ColumnCount { get { return _kcolumnCount; } }
    public int RowCount { get { return _krowCount; } }

    public Model()
    {
        Letters = new ObservableCollection<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount * RowCount; i++)
        {
            Letters.Add(' ');
        }
    }

    public void UpdateLetters()
    {
        char[] characters = new char[ColumnCount * RowCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Word != null && i < Word.Length)
            {
                characters[i] = Word[i];
            }
            else
            {
                characters[i] = (char)('a' + _random.Next(26));
            }
        }

        for (int i = characters.Length - 1; i > 0 ; i--)
        {
            int j = _random.Next(i + 1);

            if (i != j)
            {
                char chT = characters[i];

                characters[i] = characters[j];
                characters[j] = chT;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            Letters[i] = characters[i];
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void _UpdateValue<T>(ref T field, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            field = newValue;

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It has three key features:

1. It stores the current word.
2. It stores the current list of letters to be displayed.
3. It provides a method to cause the list of letters to be updated, based on the current word.

It also includes the values for the row and column counts of your grid.

You'll notice that this class is entirely comprehensible as the fundamental logic for your program, and yet has nothing in it that is directly related to the *implementation* of the UI.

Having written such a class, it is then very easy to create a simple XAML markup for the user interface:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO36231872RandomLetters.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO36231872RandomLetters"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:Model/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3">
      <TextBox Width="80" Text="{Binding Word}"/>
      <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Update Word"
              Margin="3,0" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Letters}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Rows="{Binding RowCount}" Columns="{Binding ColumnCount}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:Char}">
          <Button Content="{Binding}" FontSize="16"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The only thing left is the `Click` event handler (there are other ways to deal with user input, but this is the simplest and suits this particular example just fine). This goes in the code-behind for the `Window` class (i.e. *"MainWindow.xaml.cs"*):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Model model = (Model)DataContext;

    model.UpdateLetters();
}
```

This causes the `UpdateLetters()` method to be called with the *"Update Word"* button is clicked.

Of course, this is not your full program. I don't really fully understand what you mean by *"the user must create the word using every letter in every button"*. If you expect the user to click the buttons in the grid, you'll need to hook up another handler in the template for the buttons, and of course deal with the context somehow. But that's a "whole 'nother ball o' wax". I hope the above suffices to get you pointed back in the correct direction for dealing with WPF.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness and  pattience, that was a great explanation.  I will try it immediately. i will let you my code, just  for a better understanding, and finally, as  I comented in previous post,   my language programming is C, not c#, so i am not  very well at this, maybe you can suggest me some tutorials or books, to learn the "right way". thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any good resources for learning WPF. I had been looking for some myself, but gave up and just wound up diving in. I had some advantage, in that I was already familiar with the MVC pattern and related ones; a key to grasping WPF idioms is to be very strict about keeping your non-UI logic completely separate from the UI logic, something that the model/view design patterns emphasize. WPF has very good built-in support for these patterns, via its data binding mechanisms. I would recommend starting out with some very simple programs, then go on from there.

Comment: By the way, I would not get your hopes up too much that someone will look at the full project you uploaded to Google Drive. Stack Overflow is by design focused on very narrow questions, where a nice short code example suffices. We tend to shy away from bothering with questions that require inspecting and comprehending a complete program with all its various features and requirements. Try to keep things simple and you will get better results from the site (see the link I provided in my answer: [mcve]).

Comment: Hi,  I was wondering if you know how to manage Hide/show, every button in the ItemsControl. Now im trying to select a button and hide, but when a new word came, all buttons must be visible again, you know how can i do that?, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just use a different type for the `Letters` property. Instead of a collection of `char` values, create your own type that includes two properties: a `char` for the letter, and a `bool` or `Visibility` for the visibility. Then bind like `<Button Content="{Binding Letter}" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}"/>` (where I'm assuming your properties are named `Letter` and `Visibility`, of course). Then you just change the `Visibility` property to change the button's visibility. Naturally, this user-defined type must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well.

Comment: sorry,
thanks for your quickly response, you mean something like this?  

Type MyType 
 Letters As Char
   Visibility As visibiliy
End Type

Comment: Well, that VB.NET instead of C# (sort of...I think you mean `Class MyType...End Class`, and you need to make the members properties, not fields), but yes...that's essentially what I mean. As I noticed previously, it's not quite as simple as that...you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that you can change the `Visibility` property and it work. But that's the basic idea.

Comment: haha, yes peter, that's what I meant, I´ve just look in the wrong page (VB). The only thing that I can not understand is how can I choose hide  every clicked button  inside dataTemplate, and then show it all of them again to start with a new word. sorry for bother you, but I don't have much knowlegde about it.

Comment: You need to loop through your collection, and set each `Visibility` property in your custom type to `Hidden` so that they are no longer visible. At this point, you should probably make an attempt, and if you have problems, post a new question with a good [mcve].